# Getting rid of CmisRuntimeException: Error: The server sent HTTP status code 401: Unauthorized

Tags: web-services, sharepoint-2013, opencmis, apache-chemistry

I am trying to connect to SharePoint 2013 using Apache Chemistry CMIS Web services binding. I have given valid WSDL url.

Sometimes I am able to make a valid connection and perform CMIS operations. But sometimes I get the following exception trace :

org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.commons.exceptions.CmisRuntimeException: Error: The server sent HTTP status code 401: Unauthorized
    at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.bindings.spi.webservices.ObjectServiceImpl.createDocument(ObjectServiceImpl.java:92)
    at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.runtime.SessionImpl.createDocument(SessionImpl.java:751)
    at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.runtime.SessionImpl.createDocument(SessionImpl.java:882)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite$PojoCachedMethodSite.invoke(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:189)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite.call(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:53)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:128)
.................................

What is the reason for this mixed behaviour. And how do I get rid of this exception

Comment: Are you using NTLM authentication? If so, switch to basic authentication an try again. And, if you can, use the AtomPub binding. It's faster.

Comment: You have to enable Basic authentication on the server side. NTLM will never work flawless with CMIS write operations. Also, the upload limit is a server configuration.

Comment: I found that With Web Services Binding I am not able to upload a file > 52 MB. If I try to upload a large file >52 mb , it gives me 400 bad request error. I will try enabling basic authentication on server side.
Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: I enabled basic authentication on sharepoint server side. But didnt work :-(